# A link doesn't show up in Linked pages

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, linked-questions

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3577128) has a link to another answer, but neither page has a Linked section. Why?

Comment: Probably because one answer is linking to another answer, but not linking to a question.  The linked "section" in posts identifies *linked questions*, not necessarily linked answers.  No bug, here.  Indeed, you use a link to a previous answer *you gave*, in a new answer *you gave*.  Either you posted duplicate answers, which is not good to do, or you were trying to cut down on your efforts to answer a question.  But do not expect help from linked questions, unless you link a question, and not another answer you gave.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, I think the quality of the answers is completely irrelevant here (although I do think that it's ridiculous that you downvoted the old answer as well: if you think the new answer is bad because it says "apply this method", that's fine, but why is the old answer bad?). The point is that every time I had a link from one answer to another, the links were shown in the Linked section. You can go through my recent answers, you'll immediately find several examples (feel free to downvote them as well). So I claim something unexpected happened in this case.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything!  What I am attempting to say is that the "linked section" you refer to is when another *question* is linked, (whether in a question or an answer).  But that doesn't happen when another *answer* is linked.  You linked one thing; a previous answer of yours.  That does not generate a "linked question" in the "linked section" that your refer to, because you didn't link a question.  And please refrain from undue accusations against those trying to help in answering your "question"/rant, here.

Comment: @amWhy I apologize, I thought it was you who downvoted them. But what you wrote in your first comment about the questionable quality of the answer is still irrelevant. Also, you're simply ignoring what I wrote in my previous comment. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3539215), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3487135), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3480781), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3317844), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3288328) -- all these have links from answers to answers that show up in Linked. Your claim that this doesn't happen is obviously wrong.

Comment: Given your examples, you're correct.  I cannot explain the lack of "linking" in the specific case you are asking about.

Comment: This could be relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344928/313042

Comment: I have added and removed a comment linking to the other answer, now the two questions are linked to each other. (Basically, I have done the same thing I described at the end of this post on MathOverflow Meta: [Retroactively add linked questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4585).)